# Mapping hierarchical data in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

In a Hibernate application I'm working on a table with hierarchical data (Oracle Database).

For the sake of simplicity I'll put an example of a person with a father (assume the hierarchy is not fixed and can extend for more than 3 levels).

Every `Person` may own a couple of `Car`s.

```
@Entity
class Person
{
 @Id
 private String id;
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "FATHER_ID")
 private Person father;
}

@Entity
class Car
{
 @Id
 private String id;
 @ManyToOne
 private Person owner;
}
```

So far whenever we needed to fetch all cars for a person's descendants, we issued a native query fetching all descendants' ids and then a second hql query to fetch the cars themselves (using IN clause with the previously fetched ids as bind parameters).

I don't like it because it stains our code and causing us to issue more queries than we actually need.

Moreover, we are kind of abusing the IN clause, using a different number of bind parameters for many of our queries.

So I decided to try and encapsulate this hierarchical data using Hibernate.

I've tried using `@JoinFormula` to get the person's descendants as a data member like this:

```
@Entity
class Person 
{
  ...
  @JoinFormula(value = "SELECT p.id FROM Person p START WITH p.id = id CONNECT BY PRIOR p.id = father_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @OneToMany
  List<Person> descendants;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, hibernate throws an exception:

```
ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Column
```

I have tried changing the relation to `@ManyToMany`, it fixes the `ClassCastException`, but then hibernate just ignores the formula and creates a new table.

Now I'm thinking of using an sql function to retrieve descendants ids and using it inside my hql.
However I'm not quite sure on how to do this...

Any help would be much appreciated!